# Cauchy product of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j)^s}$

Tags: calculus, summation

I am trying to find Cauchy product of: $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j)^s}$$

My try: Apply Cauchy product then we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j)^s}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{l=1}^{k}\frac{1}{l(i+k-l+1)^s}$$

But it seems wrong, because I cant get the final result is $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{i-1}}{i^s}$$, where $H_{i-1}$ is the $(i-1)th$ Harmonic numbers.

Can someone give me a help here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Rewrite your expression by interchanging the summation order as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=i+1}^\infty 1/(ij^s)=\sum_{j=2}^\infty 1/j^s\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}1/i$ as required. Also, your expression can be written as the multiple zeta value $\zeta(s,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+j)^s}}
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{{i+j=n}\atop{i,j\geq 1}}\frac{1}{i}\,\frac{1}{(i+j)^s}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}\,\frac{1}{n^s}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}H_{n-1}}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we collect $i,j$ by noting $n\geq 2$ since $i,j\geq 1$.
- In (2) we eliminate $j$ by substituting $j=n-i$.